# MvcSiteMapProvider: Possible to define DynamicNodeProvider for DynamicNode?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dynamic, mvcsitemapprovider

My entire website is defined in a database. Therefore I would like to be able to define a DynamicNodeProvider for each of the route entries in my database. I was unable to find a `DynamicNodeProvider` property on the `DynamicNode` class where the `MvcSiteMapNode` *does* have such a property.

Why is the `DynamicNode` class lacking such a property? It seems like it's not possible to have a website entirely dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement DynamicNodeProviderBase and configure your provider in Mvc.sitemap xml like this:

`<mvcSiteMapNode title="Details" action="Details" dynamicNodeProvider="MvcMusicStore.Code.StoreDetailsDynamicNodeProvider, MvcMusicStore" />`

The [documentation on dynamic sitemaps](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Dynamic-sitemaps) is pretty explicit.

Comment: I would like to add a `DynamicNodeProvider` for a `DynamicNode` not for a `MvcSiteMapNode`